# Kafka retries = 0 give 'Failed to obtain partition information' error

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, kafka-producer-api

I have a Kafka producer with the following configuration. The consumer app is getting invoked even after the request.timeout.ms got exceeds, but getting timeout error in the producer. I need to restrict the consumer invocation if the timeout error happened on the consumer side. I have tried to make the retries to 0 but getting 'Failed to obtain partition information'

```
binders:
        defaultbinder:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: kafka_broker_name
                      autoCreateTopics: true
                      autoAddPartitions: false
                      replicationFactor: 1
                      configuration:
                        retries: 1
                        batch.size: 16384
                        linger.ms: 1
                        enable.idempotence: true
                        buffer.memory: 33554432
                        request.timeout.ms: 3000
                        transaction.timeout.ms: 3000
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the reason by myself. The exact error is

> Failed to obtain partition information' has been raised by the KafkaTopicProvisioner.java getPartitionsForTopic method. 'org.apache.Kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Must set retries to non-zero when using the idempotent producer.

In the configuration, I have used `enable.idempotence: true`

Comment: But your retries setting already is non zero

Comment: Yeah, but I tried to set it to 0 and got this error.